# Finding Sides/Angles of a triangle

Tags: java, geometry, trigonometry

I'm attempting to find the angles/sides of a triangle based on points that are scanned in.

So, sides are calculated, then angles. My side lengths seem to be correct, however I keep getting the wrong value for the angle. The values being used for the formula are supposed to be "height = 3" and "sideA = 3.16." Now, if I input those values directly, I get the correct result.. If I use my height and sideA variables, I get an incorrect result even though those are outputting the correct values.

Value with input of "3/3.16" = .949763-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Value with input of "height/sideA" = .74999

EDIT: Point values are "(0.0,0.0) (4.0,0.0) (3.0,3.0)"

```
public class Triangle {

private double sideA;
private double sideB;
private double sideC;
private double height;
private double x1;
private double y1;
private double x2;
private double y2;
private double x3;
private double y3;



public void setX1( double x){

  x1 = x;

}

public void setY1( double y){

  y1 = y;

}

public void setX2( double x){

  x2 = x;

}

public void setY2( double y){

  y2 = y;

}

public void setX3( double x){

  x3 = x;

}

public void setY3(double y){

  y3 = y;

}

public void setHeight(){

  height = (x3 - x1);

}

public double getHeight() {

  return height;

}

public void setLengthC(){

sideA = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2.0)
      + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2.0));
}

public double getLengthC(){

  return sideA;

}


public double getAngleA() {

  double sine = Math.asin(Math.sin(height/sideA));
  return sine;

}


}
```

And here is the tester class.

```
 import java.util.*;


public class TriangleTester {

   public static void main(String [] args){

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   Triangle test = new Triangle();



   System.out.print("Please enter a value for X1: ");
   test.setX1(scan.nextDouble());
   System.out.print("Please enter a value for Y1: ");
   test.setY1(scan.nextDouble()); 
   System.out.print("Please enter a value for X2: ");   
   test.setX2(scan.nextDouble()); 
   System.out.print("Please enter a value for Y2: ");
   test.setY2(scan.nextDouble()); 
   System.out.print("Please enter a value for X3: ");   
   test.setX3(scan.nextDouble()); 
   System.out.print("Please enter a value for Y3: ");
   test.setY3(scan.nextDouble());
   test.setLengthC();
   test.setHeight();

   System.out.println("Side a: " + test.getLengthA());
   System.out.println("Side b: " + test.getLengthB());
   System.out.println("Side c: " + test.getLengthC());
   System.out.println("Height: " + test.getHeight());
   System.out.println("Angle A: " + test.getAngleA());



    }
    }
```

Comment: Well for starters, you have a method that says, setLengthC() but it changes the value of the variable, sideA. Also, to make this question easier to answer, I recommend you point out which side is which.

Answer (score 0):

In your setLengthC() function you have sideA = distance of x2 and x1. Change this to distance of x3 and x2 so:

```
sideA = Math.sqrt(
            (Math.pow((x3 - x2), 2.0))
          + (Math.pow((y3 - y2), 2.0)));
    }
```

Comment: Also, be careful with the way you are finding the height. If a user enters the furthest south point 1st or 2nd, your value will not be correct. Instead, you should find the max Y value and subtract the min Y value from it. For some reason, you are using the X values to find the height. If your last point was not (3,3) and first point (0,0) this will not work.

Comment: I just realized my values were incorrect, I have everything mislabeled its an absolute disaster lol. Thanks for the suggestion, I was more focused on getting the answers and saw a simple solution for the height. Will implement that.

Comment: @user3344880 I recommend you clean up your code, edit your question, and once you've posted all the edits, we will definitely be able to help you out more.

Comment: Also, I am a bit confused why you think that .949763 is the correct angle for angle A? A more efficient way to do this might be to find all 3 sides by using the distance formula and implementing the SSS Triangle formula to solve for the 3 angles. http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html